# what is a keyword argument in python?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, keyword-argument

I'm a beginner working with django. When working with Class Based Views, I constantly keep getting this error:

```
Reverse for 'products.views.'filter_by_led' with arguments '()'
```

and

```
keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Sorry if I don't bring more context to the table, the point is, I don't understand what keyword arguments are, and I know that's the reason why I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Unless you have any url patterns that use keyword arguments, you basically don't need to care about the error message. All you need to know is that Django could not find a URL pattern to match.

Comment: Here's a good explanation of positional args, and keyword args: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Keyword argument are argument which are passed using their name. For example in the call

```
foo(1, 3, length=4)
```

argument 1 and 3 are usual argument whereas `length` is a keyword argument. You should read a tutorial such as [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) or [this official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

Answer (score 0):

keyword arguments (kwargs) are those represented as a dictionary

```
{'parameter_name1': value1, 'parameter_name2': value2, ...}
```

Once you get them in a function `func`, you can access to them as `kwargs['parameter_name1']`

`def func(*args, **kwargs):`   ---->  **args**: positional arguments, **kwargs**: keyword arguments